# Cassandra nodetool snapshot creates snapshot directory but not in the data directory specified

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

I am using Cassandra nodetool to take a snapshot .

The way i use it is, cd to $CASSANDRA_HOME and then do bin/nodetool snapshot . It says a snapshot directory has been created but I don't find in the data directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots are in $DATA_DIR/$KEYSPACE/$COLUMN_FAMILY/snapshots/.

Comment: Hi Richard, I checked it there, it is not available. I guess I made a blunder by installing Cassandra in MAC by doing a brew install and also tar ball install. But both will dump the snapshot in the data directory mentioned right?

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you using? The snapshots are hardlinks to the original SSTables so must be in data directory (at least, must be on the same partition but Cassandra can't assume anywhere else is on the same partition).

Comment: I am using Cassandra 1.2.6.